# evaluating integrals containing unknown functions using trapezoidal rule in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

How do I get a symbolic expression for the integration of the following function which contains an unknown function using trapezoidal rule?

$f(x) = \lambda(x) + x^2$

Integrate $\int^{b}_{a}f(x) $ using [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) with a time step of  $\Delta x_k = 0.1s$ from $t = 0s $ to $t =0.3s$

For example, desired output from Matlab for following function

$\int^{0.3}_{0} \lambda(x) + x^2$

will be approximated (using the trapezoidal rule) as

$\approx [{\frac{0.1}{2} (\;\;f(0.1)+f(0.0)\;)\;+\;\frac{0.1}{2} (\;\;f(0.2)+f(0.1)\;)\;+\frac{0.1}{2} (\;\;f(0.3)+f(0.2)\;)}] $

Your code in Matlab should be able to evaluate this expression from trapezoidal rule and give the final answer which includes the symbolic expression for the unknown $\lambda(0.0),\;\lambda(0.1),\;\lambda(0.2),\;\lambda(0.3)   $

This is how your Matlab code evaluate $f(0.1)$ as an example
$$ f(0.1) = \lambda(0.1) +\,(0.1)^2=\lambda(0.1)+0.01$$

Comment: After reading the Wikipedia page, I think it should be $\frac{0.1}{2} (f(0.0) + f(0.1)) + \frac{0.1}{2} (f(0.1) + f(0.2)) + \frac{0.1}{2} (f(0.2) + f(0.3))$, right?

Comment: @AlexVong oh yes. I am sorry. That's what it should have been. I will edit it but this is the problem i need to solve

Answer (score 0):

I come up with the code using Octave, please try if the code works for you as well.

Firstly, create the symbolic function $\lambda(x)$.

```
syms lambda(x)
```

After that, define the anonymous function $f(x)$

```
f = @(x) lambda(x) + x ^ 2
```

Next, define the trapezoidal rule as an anonymous function. (I use the formula for uniform grid.)

```
trapezoidal = @(f, a, b, delta_x) ...
               delta_x / 2 * ...
              (f(a) + ...
               sum(arrayfun(f, ...
                            (a + delta_x) : ...
                            (delta_x) : ...
                            (b - delta_x))) * 2 + ...
               f(b))
```

Finally, to get the result

```
trapezoidal(f, sym('0'), sym('3 / 10'), sym('1 / 10'))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Alex, this works but I wish the problem was that simple. For any given time, t, I actually need $\lambda(t)$ as a symbolic expression. The reason is the following: suppose $P = f(x) + f(x-1)$ then expression I should get for x = 2 must be in terms of $\lambda(x)$ The desired output in this case should be: "$5 + \lambda(1) + \lambda(0)$"

Comment: @OsaamaShehzad Can you edit the question so that it includes the real problem you are facing? I don't understand what do you mean by needing $\lambda(t)$ as a symbolic expression.

Comment: I am editing it question to display the larger goal. Please give me 5 mins

Comment: done! Please take a look at it! Thank you SO much! :)

Comment: Thank you so much but why would you make 1/10 as a symbolic expression? And this code is static. I am trying to write a dynamic solution. What i have given you in the problem is an example. In reality, this code should work for any given $f(x)$ with unknown $\lambda(x)$

Comment: @OsaamaShehzad OK I think I can rewrite the trapezoidal rule function so that it works. Stay tuned...

Comment: @OsaamaShehzad I have updated the answer, please see if the code run.